# How add libarary which don`t have compile dependencies android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I want to add [DonwloadProvider](https://github.com/JiboStore/DownloadProvider) library to my android studio project but it doesn`t have any compile dependencies.
so therefore I searched so much but did not find any related answer

**please anyone help me with this it is very important for me**

Comment: @TGMCians i have looking for compile dependencies but there is nothing .

Comment: @TGMCians therefore searched how to add libarary without compile but nothing related to this

Comment: please check this link- https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Comment: @Sangram  this link is helpfull . but can you please tell me where to create "subProject" folder as described in link

Answer (score 0):

Download the Project from the `github` and add it under your project folder

Do the following steps

```
1. Goto File -> New -> Import Module.
2. Source Directory -> Browse the project path.
3. Specify the Module Name – it is used for internal project reference.
4. Let Android Studio build the project.
Open build.gradle (Module:app) file.
```

References:
[How to add library projects](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/)